# Feasible to check out XML file from QuickLook?

Tags: plist, quicklook, xml

How can I use QuickLook to check out XML file? I just want to quickly check out the contents of a file and don't have to open it in a format that can be subsequently modified, such as in TextEdit or Vim or whatever other editors out there. I even don't like to open it in Xcode using drag and drop - just want to push <kbd>Space</kbd> and glance at the contents there.

And it looks like QLStephen doesn't support XML/plist files. So is there any alternative way to glance at it from QuickLook?

I use OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing [Textmate 2](http://macromates.com/) you get QuickLook support for a bunch of data files including XML, Json etc.

Comment: Does this work in Mavericks too? I just installed it, was able to open the App, but still cannot open XML files from QuickLook...

Comment: Yep, i'm running it in Mavericks. Did you make TextMate your default App to open XML ?

Comment: Just make it the default app but still cannot open. Also, I don't like the idea of setting it as default. Do you use QLStephen? I wonder if it conflicts with TextMate...

Comment: After I installed QLColorCode, for some reasons it worked. Ditching TextMate being default editor still works.

Comment: Thanks for the TextMate recommendation! I've long used BBEdit, but it is feeling bloated and confusing these days, so it's nice to find a stripped, but featureful text editor. I especially like "Text —> Filter Through Command…". What a great way to execute a command and have the result right in a text editor! No more copying from Terminal and pasting into BBEdit… although BBEdit probably has something similar, buried deep in some menu tree…

Answer (score 0):

CED Lecca's [ColorXML QuickLook](http://www.araneum.it/macosx/) appears to offer what you need. I am not sure if it works with OS X 10.9.

[image: ColorXML QuickLook]

Brian Oliver's article, [OS X Leopard: Extending Quick Look to support XML](http://brianoliver.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/os-x-leopard-extending-quick-look-to-support-xml/), links to other sources for useful QuickLook plug-ins.

Comment: I also recommend QLColorCode to color syntax other files aside XML: https://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/

Comment: Installed it and executed `qlmanage -r` to reload QuickLook settings, but it didn't work in my case. Also rebooted but still not working...